# Is it wrong to put a note that "Edit is in progress"?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, not-an-answer

When I answer a question, I make a brief suggestion of what is wrong and put a note that edit is in progress. I then fix the user's code to show the changes and update my answer. I was down voted twice and a user left a comment saying "Edit in progress" is not an answer. [SO Post Revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31659740/revisions)

I do agree with the user, "Edit in progress" is not an answer indeed but it is a common practice in SO to update the answer through multiple edits, is it wrong to leave a note for that?

Comment: You shouldn't click "submit" until it is a complete answer. though, there's nothing wrong with adding more to it or improving it after that. I see no benefit to adding "edit in progress" to it.

Comment: Don't do this...just don't. Write your answer, at least enough to give a quality answer then, if you want to edit with supporting links and such, go ahead

Comment: Your placeholder answer was down-voted for the lack of a spinning progressbar.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå, That was a good one. Thank you all for being kind to answer. I appreciate that :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you catch yourself writing "edit in progress" too often, then you're too preoccupied with being the first to answer. People will downvote your for that. It's fine to be first, but you need to write complete answers before hitting the submit button.

Comment: I guess its the priorities and SO's priority is the right answer and not the quickest answer :)

Comment: @Lordbalmon Yes, we typically don't have a problem with questions not being answered quickly enough.

Answer (score 13):

Do not submit incomplete answers without the expectation of said answer being poorly received.

I understand the feeling of gotta submit fast to get the points, but, the fact is if your question doesn't answer the question or doesn't have an explanation, it's very likely going to be downvoted, thus defeating the purpose of submitting it asap, and potentially affecting your ability to answer if it happens too often.

Far better to be the 2nd or 3rd answer and it be complete with explanation than being first with no explanation. You'll likely be bested by someone who answered 2nd with an explanation.